# Ошибка при компиляции в Qt

Tags: qt, компиляция

При попытке скомпилировать проект вылетает ошибка

> cannot find -lQt5Cored

Как решить данную проблему? Заранее благодарен.

Comment: `Qt5Cored` или `Qt5Core`?

Comment: :-1: ошибка: cannot find -lQt5Cored

Comment: Не компилируется под вендой или под линуксом?

Comment: не компилируется под windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добрый вечер. Наиболее вероятные причины данной ошибки следующие:

1. Отсутствует файл libQt5Cored.a. Данный файл должен находится в папке lib твоего компилятора, находящегося, в свою очередь в папке с установленным Qt. Например у меня это: C:\Qt\5.5\mingw492_32\lib. Если данного файла там нет, то можно скачать его вручную, однако лучшим вариантом будет переустановка Qt.
2. Возможно, что путь к данному файлу указан неверно. Это можно посмотреть в файле makefile.debug, находящимся в папке с build-ом твоего проекта. Открой его в текстовом редакторе и найди строчку LIBS. В ней указан путь. Должен быть аналогичен указанному в пункте 1. Если он другой, то сначала попробуй удалить все makefile, очистить и пересобрать проект. Если путь не изменится на корректный, измени его вручную.

Надеюсь поможет. В любом случае, отпишись.